# ChartJS ticks values are not correct

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm working on Angular version `11.0.4`, I'm using **ng2-charts** version `2.4.2`.
I have to render basic line charts, with some custom features.
One of the features consists of color some grid lines based on external API values.

Here's an example: for the **yValue 2**  I want to have the red color.
[image]

Since I haven't found a good solution for this problem, I'm trying this:
inside the LineChart Options, there's the **yAxes** object inside **scales**.
There's a series of callbacks ( here's the documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/axes/#callbacks ) which gives me the values of the ticks after being rendered. Based on those values I update the color values of the grid lines.

The problem is that every single callbacks that the interface provides give a series of values that are not the ones the chart renders.

This is what I have written:

```
      scales: {
    ...this.lineChartOptions.scales,
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }          
     afterTickToLabelConversion: (scale) => {
        console.log(scale);
        return scale;
      }
    }],
```

This is what the console.log prints:

[image]

And this is what the chart renders:

[image]

As you can see the console.log prints **10 values from 18 to 0**.
The chart renders the tick values from 19 to 17.

**HTML code:**

```
<canvas id="chartContainer" baseChart width="400" height="400" [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels"
[options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType"
[plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
```

Comment: I've tried every callback inside the options: afterUpdate, afterFit. Every single one gives me the same values, but the ones the chart shows.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided the ticks array contain the correct ticks if I try to print them normally: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/bfc3evz1/6/.

If you want the number 2 to be red and the rest be black your best option is to update to the latest version of chart.js which means you need to use the beta of ng2-charts, then you can make use of the scriptable options.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: ({
            tick
          }) => (tick.value === 12 ? 'red' : Chart.defaults.color)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've updated the libraries. It works. Thank you.